# Spring Rest Controller - Startup Order

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a requirement to make an endpoint available only after my application has finished starting up.

Currently I am experimenting with the Spring ApplicationListener/ContextRefreshedEvent to capture when Spring has finished initialising.

Is there any way to get it to start my custom Rest endpoint up at this point? I tried using:

```
BeanDefinitionBuilder builder = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(ReadinessIndicator.class);
beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition("readinessIndicator", builder.getBeanDefinition());
```

To add the bean at runtime but it doesn't look like its being initialised.

Comment: Can you give a little more insight? I don't work with Spring that much, but the endpoints are available after the application is finished loading, or you have something that is initialized afterwards?

Comment: why do you think your end point is online before your application has finished starting up?

Comment: Maybe he doesn't want to annotate his endpoint class as a `controller` class, and that's why he want to trigger it after init.

Answer (score 0):

As Aleksander said, endpoints are available aftee application finish loading. If you want to trigger some action after all process of initialization, you can use `@PostConstruct` annotation on the method, in a class where you have your main method. example

```
@PostConstruct
public void afterInit() {
    BeanDefinitionBuilder builder = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(ReadinessIndicator.class);
    beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition("readinessIndicator", builder.getBeanDefinition());
}
```

Comment: Using `PostContruct` for this is a bad idea... That is called when the object is created and has its dependencies injected. It doesn't wait till the whole application is started, use an `ApplicationListener` for those usecases instead.